# React useEffect stale closure while trying to poll, as well as debounce a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, closures, lodash

Happy Friday! Im just on here because I have an issue with a stale closure that is happening in my react cryptocurrency project. I have a function storing an api call that is supposed to run upon render and every 6 seconds after. It also is supposed to take the debounced input and make a call against the same api url every 500ms after the user stops typing into the input field.

```
  function handleInitPoll(baseAndQuote, side, value) {
    getSwapPrice(baseAndQuote, side, value || 0)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.price) {
          setIsLoading(true);
        } else if (res.error) {
          setInputErrorMessage(res.error);
        } else if (res.price) {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setSwapPriceInfo(res);
        }
      });
  }
```

As you can see, it has 3 arguments being passed into it.

And I am debouncing it in my onChangeHandler:

```
const debounceOnChange = useCallback(debounce(handleInitPoll, 500, pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount), []);

  const handleAssetAmount = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const formattedAmount = handleAssetAmountFormat(value);
    setFromCurrencyAmount(formattedAmount);
    validateInputAmount(formattedAmount);
    debounceOnChange(pair, transactionType, formattedAmount);
  };
```

And here is the useEffect that is polling the function:

```
  useEffect(() => {

      if (pair && transactionType && symbol === baseAsset) {
        handleInitPoll(pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount);
      }

      const timer = setInterval(handleInitPoll, 6000, pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
      };
    }
  }, [pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount, symbol]);
```

So this actually works in that it polls with the default given values and return a response from my api. Entering an amount from the textfield with the onChange handler also populates the parameter 'fromCurrencyAmount'.

However, there is an issue where the debouncing does not work. It simply makes an api call against each and every key stroke without 500ms after I stopped typing. Literally every key stroke will trigger an api call. But if I remove the `fromCurrencyAmount` state variable from the useEffect dependency array, the debouncing works in that it makes a debounced call against the api in the handleInitPoll function, but the next poll that occurs, the subsequent api parameters being sent are back to defaults instead of being a continuation of the inputs.

This is something I guess is a side effect of the variables being placed into the dependency array. I know that having the fromCurrencyAmount inside the dependency array will prevent api call from passing in default parameters but it defeats the purpose of debouncing since it will make a call on every onChange event.

Are there any solutions that you know about? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Because when you input, 'fromCurrencyAmount' will be changed and useEffect will be called, then trigged the handleInitPoll. Why don't you use debouced call back in the useEffect function?

Comment: Hey @PeterT that is certainly something I need to try. But I am not sure how to go about doing that with my code. Do you mean moving the line:

const debounceOnChange = useCallback(debounce(handleInitPoll, 500, pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount), []);

Into my useEffect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call debounceOnChange in useEffect instead of handleInitPoll:

```
  useEffect(() => {

      if (pair && transactionType && symbol === baseAsset) {
        debounceOnChange(pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount);
      }

      const timer = setInterval(handleInitPoll, 6000, pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
      };
    }
  }, [pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount, symbol]);
```

Another way is moving the first three lines from useEffect into onChange event handler, but still you need use debounceOnChange not handleInitPoll.

If you want keep the initial poll when the component first rendering, you can move this three lines into another useEffect without fromCurrenyAmount dependent:

```
  useEffect(() => {

      if (pair && transactionType && symbol === baseAsset) {
            debounceOnChange(pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount);
          }
  },[pair,transactionType,symbol]);
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! That edit did the trick! Really appreciate it. I commented earlier but I dont know maybe it was removed. @PeterT